# How to retrieve a data from a table and insert into another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to retrieve "customer_id" from Customer table and insert it into

```
fare_tariff(tariff_id, customer_id, total_price)
```

So I retrieve the customer_id from Customer table as below:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE UserName = '" + username + "' Password = '"+password +"' ", connection))
{
    string cust_id = customer_id.ToString();
    SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        cust_id = myReader["customer_id"].ToString();
    }

    int c_id = Convert.ToInt32(cust_id);

    myReader.Close();
    custID(c_id);
}
```

and insert the customer_id into table fare_tariff like below:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO flight_reservation(tariff_id, customer_id, total_price) VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3)", connection))
{

    command.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tariff_id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customer_id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = total_price.ToString();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I declared customer_id as a variable for storing customer_id.

Problem is : tariff_id and total_price inserted successfully but the column customer_id is null yet.

Help needed.

Comment: SHOW YOUR FULL CODE IT HARD TO UNDERSTAND WHAT U ARE DOING FROM HERE

Comment: If the customer id  is null, what do you think you should do about that?

Comment: How is value transferred from `c_id` to `customer_id`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, I  declared a variable 'customer_id' as 'public' and used a method 'custID(int custID){customer_id = custID}'

Comment: @SazzadHossain: Try to put breaks on points where customer_id is assigned a value. I guess at some point its value is cleared.

Comment: @DanBracuk, customer_id is not null in the database, as it is an auto id in the Customer table. 
But somehow it is either could not be retrieved or could not be inserted.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of code by doing the entire operation in a single command and a bit more SQL.  Send all your variables in (us, pw, tariff id, and price) and pull the customer id in SQL and save.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data to the client and returning row by row back to the server 
can well produce big overhead. There's better way to do the same, 
so called "insert/select" query:

```
  using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText =
      "insert into Flight_Reservation(\n" +
      "            Customer_Id,\n" +
      "            Tariff_Id,\n" +
      "            Total_Price)\n" +
      "     select Customer_Id,\n" +
      "            @prm_Tariff_Id,\n" +
      "            @prm_Total_Price\n" +
      "       from Customer\n" +
      "      where (UserName = @prm_UserName)\n" + 
      "            (Password = @prm_Password)"; 

    command.Parameters.Add("@prm_Tariff_Id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = tariff_id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@prm_Total_Price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = total_price.ToString();
    command.Parameters.Add("@prm_UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = username;
    command.Parameters.Add("@prm_Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = password;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```